# Using a for loop to search an array

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i ++) // Checks every position of array
{
    arr[i] = str.charAt(i); // Ignore this, not needed

    if (arr[i] != ',' || arr[i] != '.' || arr[i] != '$') // Checks every position of array to see if any character equals a comma, decimal point, or a dollar sign
    {

        // Ignore below
        /*
        valueString = String.valueOf(value);
        numOfAsterisks = arr.length - valueString.length();

        for (int asterisk = 0; asterisk <= numOfAsterisks; asterisk ++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println((int)value);
        */
    }
}
```

Here, what I want to do is to check an array of characters and see if the array contains a comma, a decimal point, or a dollar sign. If the array does not contain any of these characters, then the commented-out portion (where it says "Ignore below") will be executed. The only problem I have here is that because `if (arr[i] != ',' || arr[i] != '.' || arr[i] != '$')` is under the outside `for` loop, the commented-out part is executed multiple times. I need the code to execute only once, but still check each position of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what you actually want is something like this:

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    if(c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '$') {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found) {
    /* Your commented-out code */
}
```

Note that this can also be formulated as such:

```
skip: {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '$')
            break skip;
    }
    /* Your commented out code goes here. */
}
```

Choose for yourself which you like more. :)

Comment: aaand you beat me by a minute :D. Exact same approach I had as well